# RDD with keys and dicts to dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data of many temperature measures from different times and continents.
I load the data to an rdd (i gave in this code sample example of the data), combine it by key and then transform the list of dicts to dataframe.

```
def to_list(a):
    return [a]


def append(a, b):
    a.append(b)
    return a


def extend(a, b):
    a.extend(b)
    return a


def main():
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
    parsing_obj = [[('Africa', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})], [('Africa', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})],
                   [('America', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})], [('America', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})],
                   [('Africa', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})]]

    rdd = sc.parallelize(parsing_obj)
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda l: l[0]).combineByKey(to_list, append, extend)
    print rdd.collect()
```

Which output this structure of data:

```
[
('Africa', [{'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}, {'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}, {'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}]),
('America', [{'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}, {'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}])
]
```

\
Is there way to do it without foreach every key of the rdd in the driver, create dataframe and save to hdfs?
I'm looking to more parallel and generic way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following

```
parsing_obj = [[('Africa', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})], [('Africa', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})],
               [('America', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})], [('America', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})],
               [('Africa', {'time': '1', 'temp': '2'})]]

df = sc.parallelize(parsing_obj).toDF(['info'])
df = df.select(df.info._1.alias('country'), df.info._2.alias('info'))
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.groupBy(df.country).agg(F.collect_list(df.info).alias('info'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

which would give you

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|country|info                                                                             |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Africa |[Map(temp -> 2, time -> 1), Map(temp -> 2, time -> 1), Map(temp -> 2, time -> 1)]|
|America|[Map(temp -> 2, time -> 1), Map(temp -> 2, time -> 1)]                           |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And you can save it as a `parquet` file as

```
df.coalesce(1).write.parquet('path to parquet file`)
```

**Updated**

If you don't want the `schema` of the table to be saved and want to save it as *plain text csv* then you would *need to convert the dict and arrays to plain texts*. I have *defined a `udf` function for converting the dict to text json and used `concat_ws` to convert all columns into csv text*

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
import json
def makeStringFunc(list):
    return '['+', '.join(json.dumps(x).replace("\"", "'") for x in list)+']'

makeStringUdf = F.udf(makeStringFunc, T.StringType())
df = df.groupBy(df.country)\
    .agg(makeStringUdf(F.collect_list(df.info)).alias('info'))\
    .select(F.concat_ws(", ", F.col('country'), F.col('info')))
```

which should be

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|concat_ws(, , country, info)                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Africa, [{'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}, {'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}, {'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}]|
|America, [{'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}, {'temp': '2', 'time': '1'}]                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And you can save it using `csv` function as

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("path to ouput path")
```

Comment: Parquest doesn't help me, I need csv format. i tried to save this df to csv but it doesnt support save this type of objects.

Comment: Yes maps and arrays are not supported in csv and should not be supported. Do you want to convert them to strings?